# How do I get a value of Windows.Media.Colors using a string?

Tags: c#, reflection, colors

I want to take a string like "Green" and get the `Color` type property of `Colors` that is named "Green", but I just can't figure how.

`InvokeMember` requires an object instance to invoke the named member on, but all the `Color` properties of `Colors` are static, and not available on an instance of `Colors`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it what you need?

```
var color = (Color)ColorConverter.ConvertFromString("Green");
```

it gets color by name using [ColorConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.colorconverter%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) from `Windows.Media`. It is equivalent to:

```
var color = Color.Green;
```

Comment: That's `System.Drawing.Color`, not ` System.Windows.Media.Color`. The former is used in WinForms, and the latter in WPF.

Comment: @ProfK what about that?

Comment: @ProfK I mean what about my edit, I changed it to use `ColorConverter` which returns `Windows.Media.Color`

Comment: That works a charm, thanks. Your edit wasn't visible yet when I made my last comment.